# Forcing change detection when an angular service value changes

Tags: javascript, angular

I've got a function that checks the value of an observable and based on that value performs some logic to change the value of a variable that I've defined in a service.   Everything is working as it should except that the changed value is not rendering (updating) in the web component through string interpolation when it gets changed.  It is being changed correctly in the service (when I console.log it is coming back correctly) but just not getting it to update the component for some reason.  I've read a lot about ngZone, ChangeDetectorRef etc. and have implemented those strategies on other areas where I've had update issues in the past, but for some reason they are not working here.  Code below, any guidance would be appreciated as I've banged my head against this one for a while.

```js
//From the component where I'm performing the checks on the observable.  The component where I'm doing the string interpolation on the data service value is a different component

ngOnInit(){
this.myObservable$ = this.scanitservice.decodedString$.subscribe(data => {
      if (
        data ==
        this.adventuredata.exhibit[this.adventuredata.adventure.currentAmount]
          .target
      ) {
        this.adventuredata.sharedVariables.guideText =
          'You found the right clue!  Great job!  Answer the question correctly to claim your prize.';
        console.log(this.adventuredata.sharedVariables.guideText);
        this.showQuiz = true;
        this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
        console.log('Evaluated as matched');
      }
    });
}

//From the data service 
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdventuredataService {
  constructor() {}
  
  sharedVariables = {
    guideText: '',
    quizText: ''
  };
 }
```

```html
 <div class="card-body float-right m-0 p-0">
    <img
      src="{{ this.adventuredata.adventure.guideImage }}"
      alt=""
      class="card-img-top w-25 float-left"
    />
    <span class="card-text p-0">
      {{ this.adventuredata.sharedVariables.guideText }}
    </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why do you write "this" in the html? Angular knows on which scope he is referring to.

Comment: Please try and build a minimal [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) reproducing the issue.